# About checking fields around in 2 dimensional array [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I know it might sound stupid, but i got to ask.

It's about that easy thing.

You have a 2 dimensional array, with elements inside or empty, then you get some location(x and y) and i have to draw one field from the free fields around.

I know how to do it, it just doesn't seems ... elegant or nice.
The way i was doing it was checking if i'm on the max left, max right, top, bottom, etc. Then if there is something in fields around, and then rand().

It's just so long and seems so unpleasent.
I don't know if there's shorter way? Thanks.

And sorry for my english, doing my best.

Comment: your question is a bit ambiguous, can you give a concrete example of what you need?

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some performance issues. The most critic situation is when you have point `[x, y]` in the corner, `rand()` can possibly select the invalid elements multiple times, so you have to `rand()` and check again.

The way I'd do it, is to check for available neighbours and push each valid neighbour into `std::vector`. After that, there's only one random number generation which chooses one element within this vector:

```
std::vector<Coordinate> validNeighbours;
// Coordinate is a struct with x and y integers, you can use std::pair<int, int> or the very pointers to the elements

if(/* has neighbour to the left*/)
    validNeighbours.push_back(Coordinate(x - 1, y));

// check in other directions

Coordinate c = validNeighbours[std::rand() % validNeighbours.size()];
```

You might also want to check whether `validNeighbours` is not empty before performing the modulo, in case you have just 1x1 array (`validNeighbours.size()` is 0).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array of dimensions *height* and *width*, I would use an array of dimensions *height+2* and *width+2*. Then you can fill the border cells with whatever dummy value makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's a school project, so i can't use STL.  --- to one of the anwsers.

But i got my own solution :)
I made my structure Vector( but it's like position vector, not array-vector), and i got this code, anyway i think it's the shortest way, thanks for all the help:

```
Vector Organism::FindFreeSpace()
{
int height=home->GetHeight();
int width=home->GetWidth();

Vector* choices;

Vector shift;


if(location.x==0 || location.x==width-1)
{
    if(location.y==0 || location.y==height-1)
    {

        choices= new Vector[2];
        choices[0]=( location.x==0 ? Vector(1,0) : Vector(-1,0));
        choices[1]=( location.y==0 ? Vector(0,1) : Vector(0,-1));

        ShuffleChoices(choices, 2);

        for(int h=0;h<2;h++)
        {
            if(home->IsFree(choices[h]+location)==true)
            {
                location+=choices[h];
                shift=choices[h];
                delete[] choices;
                return shift;
            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        choices=new Vector[3];
        choices[0]=( location.x==0 ? Vector(1,0) : Vector(-1,0));
        choices[1]=Vector(0,1);
        choices[2]=Vector(0,-1);

        ShuffleChoices(choices, 3);

        for(int h=0;h<3;h++)
        {
            if(home->IsFree(choices[h]+location)==true)
            {
                location+=choices[h];
                shift=choices[h];
                delete[] choices;
                return shift;
            }

        }

    }

}
else if(location.y==0 || location.y==height-1)
{

    choices=new Vector[3];
    choices[0]=( location.y==0 ? Vector(0,1) : Vector(0,-1));
    choices[1]=Vector(1,0);
    choices[2]=Vector(-1,0);

    ShuffleChoices(choices, 3);

    for(int h=0;h<3;h++)
    {
        if(home->IsFree(choices[h]+location)==true)
        {
            location+=choices[h];
            shift=choices[h];
            delete[] choices;
            return shift;
        }

    }


}
else
{

    choices=new Vector[4];
    choices[0]=Vector(0,1);
    choices[1]=Vector(1,0);
    choices[2]=Vector(-1,0);
    choices[3]=Vector(0,-1);

    ShuffleChoices(choices, 4);

    for(int h=0;h<4;h++)
    {
        if(home->IsFree(choices[h]+location)==true)
        {
            location+=choices[h];
            shift=choices[h];
            delete[] choices;
            return shift;
        }

    }

}



return Vector(0,0);
}
```

I know, you won't get it all, but you should get the idea of what have i done.

Comment: Yea, about that it's said i can't accept my anwser in 2 days, so i'm not sure how to close this topic...